# Extracting Member who did not contribute

Tags: mysql

How do you find out who did not contribute to a particular fund raiser that we all just did. There are many titles to the different charities,  I however just want to extract the non-contributors for a particular charity title. Is there anyway to do this? When I do the the syntax below it comes up as an empty set. The search is done by way of the table Id matching and left joins. Please see below.

```
SELECT  
    moiid, 
    trim(concat(name.fname,' ' ,name.mname,' ',name.lname)) as Brother, 
    name.moiid as Members_ID, 
    sum(otherpay.othpayamt) as NO_Contribution, 
    quadlt.ltfname as quad
FROM name  
LEFT JOIN OTHERPAY  ON name.moiid = otherpay.othpaymoiid
LEFT JOIN quadlt  ON name.quadlt = quadlt.ltid
WHERE Otherpay.othpaytitle like '%food drive%'
AND otherpay.othpaymoiid IS NULL 
AND name.type = 'BOI'
AND name.type <> 'jrboi'
AND name.city = 'SUFFOLK'
GROUP BY brother
ORDER BY name.quadlt, brother
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add conditions to the where clause for tables that are `left joined`, you effectively turn them into an inner join, requiring them to return records.
You can move the conditions to the join itself:

```
SELECT  moiid, trim(concat(name.fname,' ' ,name.mname,' ',name.lname)) as Brother, name.moiid as Members_ID, sum(otherpay.othpayamt) as NO_Contribution, quadlt.ltfname as quad
FROM name  
LEFT JOIN OTHERPAY  
  ON name.moiid = otherpay.othpaymoiid 
  AND Otherpay.othpaytitle like '%food drive%'
LEFT JOIN quadlt  ON name.quadlt = quadlt.ltid
WHERE  
otherpay.othpaymoiid IS NULL 
AND name.type = 'BOI'
AND name.type <> 'jrboi'
AND name.city = 'SUFFOLK'
GROUP BY brother
ORDER BY name.quadlt, brother
```